# Neo4j Store Data In Array Or User Super Node

Tags: neo4j

In early editions of Neo4j, Super nodes were typically seen as a bad thing for performance.  I have not seen too much about that recently with the 2.X and 3.X releases so was wondering if that was still a problem.

The issue I have is I need to store a finite number of options for a specific Node type.  For example, Person and favorite colors.  I can store an array in the Person Node that stores the colors the user likes, or I can create a Node for each color and then create a relationship from the Person to the Color Node.  It seems the super node option would be faster to query but am worried as super nodes were bad in the past.

If I am trying to look up people who like a specific color, what's the recommended way to store such data in Neo?

Comment: I'd go with supernodes. If you use arrays, your query will have something like `MATCH (p:Person) WHERE $color in p.favColors RETURN p`, which (AFAIK) cannot rely on indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the major issue here will be that the Color node will become a very connected node.

Maybe you need an Options subgraph to have a template of these options and then :

- copy template node option to link this copy with the main entity node

or

- copy only the choosen option into a property of the main entity node, like your array proposition

or, if your option has no properties

- add label onto your main entity node

I think, even with the increase in performance of hyperlinked nodes with newer Neo4j versions, the read/write time will be always more than the one who has less.

I hope this help a bit.